# Which folder can I find cache files for Safari?

Tags: finder, safari, macos

Not the cache in `~/library/caches/`. I have found it before, with names similar to "FFYWRMQ7RK4CBV2GWNXVTF7IS9DZ9STNWKZHMPPWRI". The folder does not only include images, but also html code. There are no extensions to the files and Finder treats them as "Documents".

Comment: I believe it is in `~/Library/Safari`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safari stores caches in a variety of locations.

- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/WebKitCache/Version 4/Blobs/`

  ```
  /Users/grgarside/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/WebKitCache/Version 4/Blobs
  ├── 0021FEDCF99DEF9CF6541CFD0452506088B12852
  ├── 004089E39B7864F9F59CDDD6A6F9DD367B04D0F8
  ├── 006E98D122D8E9C45F00B5C4A593E7724D63DC36
  └── …
  ```
- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/WebKitCache/Version 4/Records/`

  ```
  /Users/grgarside/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/WebKitCache/Version 4/Records
  ├── georgegarside.com
  │   ├── 12E9261CD298A4DD2A040FC876282A3C85482568
  │   ├── 1508307FB54D5E0C7B12B652D3346456BF60516E
  │   ├── 1C59CCC7FBA99C7A0FA1628F21298C7FD5D3BFCC
  │   ├── 1C59CCC7FBA99C7A0FA1628F21298C7FD5D3BFCC-body
  │   ├── 49C6B9C71D1DFD0B1D162E4E9A76724E67CD9FED
  │   ├── …
  ```
- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/fsCachedData/`

  ```
  /Users/grgarside/com.apple.Safari/Cache
  ├── 01151514-275B-4649-AE99-6C572F07A05D
  ├── 0531E0C2-2270-41D6-BD17-165882859A4B
  ├── 13E52A0F-0E47-4106-9E43-D0DA78AA78B7
  └── …
  ```
- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db`
- `~/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db`

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. I didn't find it because I had deleted it.

Comment: Can they be viewed in html format?

Comment: For an updated answer (e.g. the location in 10.15 Monterey) see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388678

Comment: @Shayan If you're looking to retrieve lost data, page caches, I had luck opening the WebKitCache folder in VS Code and performing a search (cmd+shift+f) for key words. I'm seeing gigs of intact js, css and html files all with cryptic file names. –