# Does Safari have an image Cache storing images from frequently visited webpages locally? If so where is it located

Tags: safari, history, browser-history

A website I use frequently recently changed an image that, in retrospect, I need and really should have saved. With other browsers I was able to just go into the cache files and find the locally saved image that the browser stores to save time. But I'm having g issues in Safari.

I looked in a this folder and there's only one image in **all** the subfolders:

- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari`

I also ran the folder

- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/`

through an app called [FruitJuicer](https://echoone.com/filejuicer/userguide) (that extracts Cache images from the rollup) with no luck. There was only one file found: which was an icon.

What might a folder like that be named? Is mine just empty? And if so, why? I havent cleared my cache.

Answer (score 3):

It does, but the location moved to the ~/Library/Containers folder:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/WebKitCache/...
```

and there:

```
./Version\ 16/Blobs/
./Version\ 16/Records/[randomized_folder_names]/
```

Comment: If you're looking to retrieve lost data, page caches, I had luck opening the WebKitCache folder in VS Code and performing a search (cmd+shift+f) for key words. I'm seeing gigs of intact js, css and html files all with cryptic file names. –

Comment: How do you view these as images?